# SQL Remove duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and my current sql query is:-

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LastName,', ',FirstName)AS 'Name',</li>
    City,
    Country,
    ShipCity AS 'Shipped City'
From 
    itstudies.employees
INNER JOIN
    Orders
ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
WHERE City = ShipCity;
```

This query shows the output as:-

(Only part of the output is shown.)

```
Name            City     Country     Shipped City
Smith, Jo       York       UK            York
Avery, Paul     Dallas     USA           Dallas
Avery, Paul     Dallas     USA           Dallas 
Kris, Jan       York       UK            York
Kris, Jan       York       UK            York
Hill, Ros       Boston     USA           Boston
```

I need to take out the duplicates and change the query to show:-

```
Name            City     Country     Shipped City
Smith, Jo       York       UK            York
Avery, Paul     Dallas     USA           Dallas
Kris, Jan       York       UK            York
Hill, Ros       Boston     USA           Boston
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

but usually it is better to have a look at where the duplicates come from and work with a

```
GROUP BY
```

In this case you join with ORDERS and thus get duplicates for all orders of an employee. Is this join necessary? You could use

```
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Orders WHERE Orders.EmployeeId=Employees.EmployeeId)
```

to get only employees who ordered.

Comment: Yes thank you so much - I used DISTINCT and it worked - just goes to show how easy it can be when you know what to do...!

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Use the DISTINCT keyword.

You can refer to http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp for more details ;)

Comment: Many thanks for the link - you are correct in using Distinct.